# Как правильно выбрать разрешение для пиксельной игры в юнити и настроить камеру?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-faq

Я начал делать игру в пиксельном стиле и столкнулся с проблемой, что понятия не имею как правильно настроить камеру и выбрать разрешение экрана под пиксели. Подскажите, как правильно настроить юньку. Если есть ссылки на понятный гайд, буду благодарен. Фон игры нарисован в 320x200. 2d игра.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используй PixelPerfectCamera

Пример настройки:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CU4YjSZNTnY

Или гугли: "Crisp Pixel Art with Unity" , "Pixel Perfect Camera unity"

Да и вообще можешь покопаться вот здесь: https://blog.unity.com/technology/pixel-perfect-2d

А здесь проэкт-пример от юнити:

https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/2d-pixel-perfect